# Converting small number to BigInteger type in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, biginteger

I need to convert small number to a BigInteger type but it results zero.
consider following code:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(0.6);
var res = BigInteger.Pow(x, 10) / Factorial(30);
```

in the first line 0.6 conversion to BigInteger results zero and the entire code return wrong result.
any idea?

Comment: If `Factorial` returns a `BigInteger` you should be doing `BigInteger.Pow(x, 10).Divide(Factorial(30))`. As far as the first line goes have you tried `new BigInteger(Convert.toDouble("0.6"))` just to see if that works? I'd be curious.

Answer (score 1):

The integer part of `0.6` is `0` so the result is correct.

if you want use `Math.Round()` to convert to the rounded integer which in your case is `1`.

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(Math.Round(0.6));
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

"Floating-point values are truncated before they are assigned to the BigInteger." Hence, see the following code snippet (from source):

> ```
> BigInteger bigIntFromDouble = new BigInteger(179032.6541);
> Console.WriteLine(bigIntFromDouble);
> // The example displays the following output: 
> //   179032
> ```

As a result, your `BigInteger x = new BigInteger(0.6);` results zero because of the truncate...which is expected behavior.